# JQuery UI Autocomplete results using categories, setting category headings height

Tags: css, jquery-ui, autocomplete

Using the code and CSS on the JQuery UI website, the category list item heights are set to overlap all the items in the previous category. I cannot figure out where this is done.

Why wouldn't each item be positioned beneath the previous item (term or category) in the list with the category and term items just having a different formatting/box size?

Comment: can you put ur code in jsfiddle?

Comment: I'm just using the code from the Jquerry UI website. Specifically the category code.

Comment: Go to http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#categories and inspect a category list item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the missing `float:left` rule that causes this.